# How to add new quotes examples into an object existing array, through click event listener method, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

everyone!
This is my first post here, so I will try to do my best to ask properly and exposed right my doubts and what I tried so far.

I've been trying to create one quotes generator, with a few features more.

I already put 7 quotes examples, as objects into the array and leaved 3 "spaces free", counting from ID 8 to 10 to the users can add more quotes examples through the "Add new quote button"

I tried to create the logic behind this (picking the HTML input field value typed by the user, add to new existing array through the Event Listener method, clicking on the button) as I commented in the last part of the JS file, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

So, if you guys please can give me a hand, I appreciate it!

PS. the ID key value of the object array it's a mandatory value.

Thanks in advance!

---

```js
let quotes = [
    {
        id: 0,
        author: "Nelson Mandela",
        quote: "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall."
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        author: "Walt Disney",
        quote: "The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing."
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        author: "Steve Jobs",
        quote: "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking."
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        author: "Eleanor Roosevelt",
        quote: "If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor."
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        author: "Oprah Winfrey",
        quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough."
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        author: "Oprah Winfrey",
        quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough."
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        author: "James Cameron",
        quote: "If you set your goals ridiculously high and it's a failure, you will fail above everyone else's success."
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        author: "John Lennon",
        quote: "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans."
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        author: "",
        quote: ""
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        author: "",
        quote: ""
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        author: "",
        quote: ""
      },
  ];

//Var to select the "generate quote" button
var btnQuotes = document.getElementById('new-quote');
// console.log(btnQuotes)

//Var to select the "quote message display"
var quoteDisplay = document.getElementById('quote')
// console.log(quoteDisplay)

//Var to select the "author message display"
var authorDisplay = document.getElementById('author')
// console.log(authorDisplay)

//Var to select the "Add quotes button"
var addNewQuotes = document.getElementById('add-quotes-button')
// console.log(addNewQuotes)



//function to display the content of the array "quotes", after click
//in the "generate quote button"
btnQuotes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    // console.log(random);
    quoteDisplay.innerText = quotes[random].quote
    authorDisplay.innerText = quotes[random].author;
}) 

// addNewQuotes.addEventListener('click', function (){
//   authorInput = document.getElementById('addauthor').value;
//   // console.log(authorInput);
//   quotesInput = document.getElementById('addquote').value;
//   // console.log(quotesInput);
//   quotes.push(authorInput)
// })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap');

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg fill='%23000000' fill-opacity='0.09' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Ccircle cx='3' cy='3' r='3'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='13' cy='13' r='3'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.quote-container {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1250px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.quote-text {
    font-size: 2.90rem;
}

.long-quote {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-quote-left {
    font-size: 4rem
}

/* .quote-author {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
} */

#author {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;  
}


.button-container {
    margin: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

input {
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid rgb(170, 169, 169);
    text-align: center;
    height: 32px; 
    outline: none;
}

b {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(75, 86, 240);
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0.3rem rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.65);
}

button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(35, 50, 255);
}

button:active {
    transform: translate(0, 0.3rem);
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}


/* Media Query: Tablet or Smaller devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .quote-container {
        margin: auto 20px;
    }

    .quote-text {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    #form-container {
        margin: auto 20px;
    }

    #new-quotes-container button {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin: 30px 20px;
    }

    b {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

    <title>Mini Project - Quotes generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form-container">
        <form onsubmit="return false">
            <div id="new-quotes-container">
              <label for="author"><b>Author:</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add new author here" name="addauthor" id="addauthor" required>
          
              <label for="quote"><b>Quote:</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add new quote here" name="addquote" id="addquote" required>
              
              <button type="submit" id="add-quotes-button">Register new quote</button>
            </div>
          </form>

    <section class="quote-container" id="quote-container">
        <!-- Quotes here-->
        <div class="quote-text">
            <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
            <span id="quote">Generate your quote pressing the button bellow!</span>
            <span id="author">Author's name</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Author -->
        <!-- <div class="quote-author">
            <span id="author">Buddha</span>
        </div> -->

        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="like-button" id="like" tittle="Like this quote!">
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="new-quote">Generate quote</button>
        </div>
    </section>        


    <!-- Script -->
    <script = src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did most part right, just needed to add the `object` to the `quotes` array. I think you were adding a `string` to that `array` which was breaking your code. Consider below snippet for reference.

```js
const quotes = [
    {
        id: 0,
        author: "Nelson Mandela",
        quote: "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall."
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        author: "Walt Disney",
        quote: "The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing."
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        author: "Steve Jobs",
        quote: "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking."
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        author: "Eleanor Roosevelt",
        quote: "If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor."
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        author: "Oprah Winfrey",
        quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough."
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        author: "Oprah Winfrey",
        quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough."
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        author: "James Cameron",
        quote: "If you set your goals ridiculously high and it's a failure, you will fail above everyone else's success."
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        author: "John Lennon",
        quote: "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans."
      }
  ];

//Var to select the "generate quote" button
const btnQuotes = document.getElementById('new-quote');
// console.log(btnQuotes)

//Var to select the "quote message display"
const quoteDisplay = document.getElementById('quote')
// console.log(quoteDisplay)

//Var to select the "author message display"
const authorDisplay = document.getElementById('author')
// console.log(authorDisplay)

//Var to select the "Add quotes button"
const addNewQuotes = document.getElementById('add-quotes-button')
// console.log(addNewQuotes)



//function to display the content of the array "quotes", after click
//in the "generate quote button"
btnQuotes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    // console.log(random);
    quoteDisplay.innerText = quotes[random].quote
    authorDisplay.innerText = quotes[random].author;
}) 

// to test this, you can set quotes as an empty array and add a quote and see it work
addNewQuotes.addEventListener('click', function (){
  let author = document.getElementById('addauthor').value;
  let quote = document.getElementById('addquote').value;
  // you can add any validations - like both items should be non empty before you push
  quotes.push({
    id: quotes.length,
    author,
    quote
  });
  console.log(quotes);
})
```

I have also hosted the codepen at - [Codepen for Quote generator](https://codepen.io/jaybhatt21/pen/VwpjwYm) if you want to verify

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works flawless! I even check and don't needed to let a few "ID's" with empty space to assign in the array the new quotes. The code that you writed already add the ID, author name and new quote. Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all, if you could upvote the answer and mark it as correct for reference :) @MarcosNulman
About the empty items, I thought it made it more scalable as you need to do any extra logic. You can have some validation before adding, I left that part out :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let quotes = [
    {
        id: 0,
        author: "Nelson Mandela",
        quote: "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall."
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        author: "Walt Disney",
        quote: "The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing."
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        author: "Steve Jobs",
        quote: "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking."
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        author: "Eleanor Roosevelt",
        quote: "If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor."
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        author: "Oprah Winfrey",
        quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough."
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        author: "Oprah Winfrey",
        quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough."
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        author: "James Cameron",
        quote: "If you set your goals ridiculously high and it's a failure, you will fail above everyone else's success."
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        author: "John Lennon",
        quote: "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans."
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        author: "",
        quote: ""
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        author: "",
        quote: ""
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        author: "",
        quote: ""
      },
  ];

//Var to select the "generate quote" button
var btnQuotes = document.getElementById('new-quote');
// console.log(btnQuotes)

//Var to select the "quote message display"
var quoteDisplay = document.getElementById('quote')
// console.log(quoteDisplay)

//Var to select the "author message display"
var authorDisplay = document.getElementById('author')
// console.log(authorDisplay)

//Var to select the "Add quotes button"
var addNewQuotes = document.getElementById('add-quotes-button')
// console.log(addNewQuotes)



//function to display the content of the array "quotes", after click
//in the "generate quote button"
btnQuotes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    // console.log(random);
    quoteDisplay.innerText = quotes[random].quote
    authorDisplay.innerText = quotes[random].author;
}) 

addNewQuotes.addEventListener('click', function (){
    const nextEmptyQuote = quotes.find(({ author, quote }) => !author && !quote);
    if (!nextEmptyQuote) return alert('you cannot add any quotes any more')
    nextEmptyQuote.quote = document.getElementById('addquote').value;
   nextEmptyQuote.author = document.getElementById('addauthor').value;

})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap');

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg fill='%23000000' fill-opacity='0.09' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Ccircle cx='3' cy='3' r='3'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='13' cy='13' r='3'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.quote-container {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1250px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.quote-text {
    font-size: 2.90rem;
}

.long-quote {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-quote-left {
    font-size: 4rem
}

/* .quote-author {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
} */

#author {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;  
}


.button-container {
    margin: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

input {
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid rgb(170, 169, 169);
    text-align: center;
    height: 32px; 
    outline: none;
}

b {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(75, 86, 240);
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0.3rem rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.65);
}

button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(35, 50, 255);
}

button:active {
    transform: translate(0, 0.3rem);
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}


/* Media Query: Tablet or Smaller devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .quote-container {
        margin: auto 20px;
    }

    .quote-text {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    #form-container {
        margin: auto 20px;
    }

    #new-quotes-container button {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin: 30px 20px;
    }

    b {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

    <title>Mini Project - Quotes generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form-container">
        <form onsubmit="return false">
            <div id="new-quotes-container">
              <label for="author"><b>Author:</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add new author here" name="addauthor" id="addauthor" required>
          
              <label for="quote"><b>Quote:</b></label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add new quote here" name="addquote" id="addquote" required>
              
              <button type="submit" id="add-quotes-button">Register new quote</button>
            </div>
          </form>

    <section class="quote-container" id="quote-container">
        <!-- Quotes here-->
        <div class="quote-text">
            <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
            <span id="quote">Generate your quote pressing the button bellow!</span>
            <span id="author">Author's name</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Author -->
        <!-- <div class="quote-author">
            <span id="author">Buddha</span>
        </div> -->

        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="like-button" id="like" tittle="Like this quote!">
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="new-quote">Generate quote</button>
        </div>
    </section>        


    <!-- Script -->
    <script = src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```